# Backwards of count in Excel/Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a row of cells in a spreadsheet with nonnegative integers in them, say 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  Later in the same row, starting say in column 11, I want to have a particular text entry, then the next cell is blank, then the two cells after that have the same text as cell 11, then another blank cell, then three cells have the same text, then a blank, then four text cells, then blank, then 5 text cells.

Notice the number of cells with text between blank cells is determined by the number in the cells earlier in the row.

Then I want to do the same for many more rows of cells with nonnegative integers in them.

I can't even find good search terms to help me figure out what to search for. Search engines keep spitting out stuff using various forms of the COUNT function, when what I need is kind of the reverse of that.

This can be in Excel or Sheets.

Link to sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IPC6lvb9MQSDLxOus08kwqVWPNlD2HyWIaf-P50zm2Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The most efficient and effective way to receive help is to share a link to a spreadsheet with a small but realistic sample of data set up in it. Manually enter all data where you want formulas to produce it. Leave notes as to where the formula(s) should be. Be sure to set the link's Share permission (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor," so that contributors here can access the sheet data, test, and leave any solutions.

Comment: Hi there @VictoriaAnnSapko! Please share an example Sheet that shows the initial/desired situation of your project. To ensure a good approach, please clarify what is your final goal in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need (vertically?):

`=arrayformula(substitute(query(flatten(split(rept("text"&"|",A2:A6)&"*","|")),"where Col1 is not null",1),"*",))`

[image]

Horizontal approach, working down column A, ignoring blank cells (formula shown in cell `C1`):

`=arrayformula(transpose(substitute(query(flatten(if(A2:A<>"",split(rept("text"&"|",A2:A)&"*","|"),)),"where Col1 is not null",1),"*",)))`

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I need, except for the whole horizontal/vertical thing.  

Is it possible to transpose this to being horizontal vs. vertical without doing a copy/paste transpose on both ends?  Not having to do that on a dozen data sets would be very useful.  I am not familiar with some of these commands, so I can't tell how to do that.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need, except for the horizontal/vertical thing.  Is it possible to transpose this to being horizontal vs. vertical without doing a copy/paste transpose on both ends?  Not having to do that on a dozen data sets would be very useful.  I am not familiar with some of these commands, so I can't tell how to do that.

Also, is this going to work with a few blank cells appended on the end of the data in the range in the formula?  Not all rows of data are the same length.  They will produce the same number of cells with "text" in them with interspersed blanks, barring errors.

Comment: I've added a horizontal approach to the solution. If you can share a sample sheet with examples of the cells you describe (and update your question), I'll take a look to see what the impact is and what can be done.

Comment: Having the output horizontal is great, but I have many rows of horizontal input, so having the input still vertical is problematic.  Will the horizontal method still work if my data is in A2:L2 rather than B2:B10?  I put a link to a sample worksheet in the original post, but here's another [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IPC6lvb9MQSDLxOus08kwqVWPNlD2HyWIaf-P50zm2Q/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

If value  that you want to replicate is in H2 and you want to copy it up to 5 times, you should use:

```
=split(join("|";ArrayFormula(rept(H2&" ";sequence(5))));"| ";true;false)
```

To explain how it works I divide it into stages:

[image]

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but it appears that the multistage approach will make it difficult to do the same with the next row of data, and so on.  There is a single stage answer below, but it works vertically rather than horizontally.  I will try to combine the two to get a single stage horizontal solution. Thanks!

Comment: @VictoriaAnnSapko I write a few stages just to explain. The formula I include here contains all the stages :-)